# how to disable autocomplete for browsers

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I try to test my app, and it will be running on the ipads.

Also, it will be used by many people.

I need to make it secure, especially account informaiton.

But, when I tested with chrome and firefox, I couldn't disable autofill function.

I tried autocomplete="false", autocomplete="off", and autocomplete="chrome-off".

Are there any tags that change the autofill behavior that could be used to fix this?

Or, Could I know the any browser if I am able to use autocomplete="off"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you applied `autocomplete='off'` to the form element?

Answer (score 0):

"As many users wouldn’t like to remember passwords, modern browsers do not support the autocomplete="off " for login fields. For login fields there is no difference if autocomplete is disabled for  fields or  fields."

"When a website sets autocomplete="off " for the  or  elements, and a username/password fields are included in it, the browser will still allow remembering these fields, and in the case that the user accepts, the browser will autofill the fields the next time the user visits that website."

"In the case, you are representing a user management page where a user can define a fresh password for a different user, and you don’t want autofill password fields, use autocomplete="new-password" therefore, this is a sign for browsers that they are not required to react to it."

Got this info from here https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-disable-browser-autocomplete-and-autofill-on-html-form-and-input-fields.html

But, using ``autocomplete="off"```it's not wrong. You can try here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_autocomplete_off2.